# Config route in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom with typescript.
I create a config file like below:

```
export interface RouteComponent {
  path?: string;
  element?: React.ComponentType<any>;
  children?: RouteComponent[];
}

const routes: RouteComponent[] = [
  {
    element: MenuLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "corp-list",
        element: CorpList,
      },
      {
        path: "/corp-list/:id",
        element: DetailCorp,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        path: "auth/login",
        element: Login,
      },
      {
        path: "auth/signup",
        element: Login,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Then, I map it to render routes in App.tsx file

```
{routes.map((route, index) => (
        <Route
          path={route.path as string}
          element={route.element}
        />
      ))}
```

It shows an error of type which the `element` in Route component take children with type of ReactNode, not the React.Component as above. But when I try to declare `element` in config routes with type of ReactNode, like :

`{ path: "corp-list", element: <CorpList /> },`

it yells "`CorpList` refers to a value, but is being used as a type here".

So, how to fix that?
And, how do you config route in react-router-dom v6, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a routes config then use the type `react-router-dom` exports, `RouteObject` in this case.

[RouteObject](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/router.ts#L86-L96)

```
/**
 * A route object represents a logical route, with (optionally) its child
 * routes organized in a tree-like structure.
 */
export interface RouteObject {
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  children?: RouteObject[];
  element?: React.ReactNode;
  index?: boolean;
  path?: string;
}
```

Key differences from your type declaration is that `element` is a `React.ReactNode` and the `children` is an array of `RouteObject`.

Import `RouteObject` and in your config pass the `element` values as JSX.

```
import { RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";

const routesConfig: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    element: <MenuLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "corp-list",
        element: <CorpList />
      },
      {
        path: "corp-list/:id",
        element: <DetailCorp />
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    children: [
      {
        path: "auth/login",
        element: <Login />
      },
      {
        path: "auth/signup",
        element: <Login />
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Don't reinvent the wheel, `react-router-dom` exports a hook to consume the routes config object and returns the matched element or null.

[useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes)

> The `useRoutes` hook is the functional equivalent of [`<Routes>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes), but it
> uses JavaScript objects instead of `<Route>` elements to define your
> routes. These objects have the same properties as normal [`<Route>`
> elements](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route), but they don't require JSX.
>
> The return value of useRoutes is either a valid React element you can
> use to render the route tree, or null if nothing matched.

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const routes = useRoutes(routesConfig);

return (
  ... nav bar ...
  {routes}
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit config-route-in-react-router-dom-v6]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but how you'd be the solution with a loader and a route protection? Mapping this way and using the proach of the dev Drew, you will face that I'll not be able to spread all the properties of a RouteObject like so `<Route key={route.path} {...route}></Route>`, you will have to put every property of a Route object `<Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} loader={router.loader} (and so on and so forth)></Route>` by this way you will not avoid problems, they will come later on.

So, I suggest using the Data Api from `react-router-dom` v6, that provides the new [RouterProvider](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider), that uses an array of RouteObject to create the router.

The Data Api docs dont provide a middleware docs or suggestion, but for me, it worked this way (that is the same as the old but in object format):

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <AuthRequired />,
    children: [
      { path: "", element: <Home /> },
      ... all other protected routes
    ],
  },
  { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
  ...
  { path: "*", element: <NotFound /> },
]);
```

and it works just like the old way, you cannot use hooks inside this object because they are not JSX, but the AuthRequired is a JSX component

```
export function AuthRequired(): ReactElement {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to={"/connect"} />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
}
```

And it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I have a route '/signup' under which there are two children routes 'fighter' and 'companion'. When a user comes to 'signup', I want one of them to be the default, like either 'fighter' or 'companion'. How can I achieve this?

```
{
  path: "/signup",
  element:
    auth.isLoggedIn && JSON.parse(auth?.token) ? (
      <Navigate to={"/fighter"} replace={true} />
    ) : (
      <SignupLayout />
    ),
  children: [
    {
      path: "fighter",
      element: <FighterSignup />,
    },
    {
      path: "companion",
      element: <CompanionSignup />,
    },
  ],
},
```