# Can't assign element with RouteObject in react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a variable to hold all my routes in react-router-dom v6, and all the documentation seems to imply i should be able to do it like this:
[image]

but i'm getting compile errors that:

> 'SPALayout' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did
> you mean 'typeof SPALayout'?

This is basically the same question as [Config route in react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198467/config-route-in-react-router-dom-v6), but I'm guessing it's working for them and not me.  What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: make sure this is a JSX file, or use the [useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook like the answer suggests

Comment: Ugh, you're right.  it was a .ts file.  changing to .tsx fixed my issue.  Stupid mistake!

Comment: I have added the solution that fixed your specific problem, I will also reach out to a moderator to determine if this should be a duplicate. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here was not having the correct file extension (.tsx). I have added this answer as it was slightly different from [Config route in react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198467/config-route-in-react-router-dom-v6).

As it was a file extension issue, I am unsure about marking this as a duplicate.